# Single quote in column name - how to select values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a column name that includes a single quote `'`. I do not manage this table so I cannot change the column name. How do I select a value from my query?

Example: `$sql['This Column's Name']`

Comment: `["This Column's Name"]`

Comment: Thank you, I jumped the gun a bit should have tried that before posting but I really appreciate the fast response.

Comment: or, escape the single quote with a backslash ... `$sql['This Column\'s Name']`

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes are accepted $sql["This Column's Name"]